# Python - Iterate each line in two CSV files and compare timestamp values

Tags: python, csv, timestamp, compare, range

I have the following two CSV files:

CSV File1:

```
Range1,2018-05-17 01:50:17+0000,2018-05-17 02:00:17+0000
Range2,2018-05-17 01:50:17+0000,2018-05-17 04:00:17+0000
Range3,2018-05-17 01:50:17+0000,2018-05-17 08:00:17+0000
```

CSV File2:

```
TimeStamp1,2018-05-17 01:59:17+0000
TimeStamp2,2018-05-17 03:59:17+0000
TimeStamp3,2018-05-17 07:59:17+0000
```

I would like to iterate thru each Range in File1 and determine which TimeStamp fall within the Range being compared. E.g. the output of my Python script would display:

Output:

```
TimeStamp1 falls within Range1
TimeStamp1, TimeStamp2 falls within Range2
TimeStamp1, TimeStamp2, TimeStamp3 falls within Range3
```

I started to write something like this but having issues getting the output and if statement to correctly iterate initially thru File1 with all lines in File2, then repeat with next line in File1 repeating all lines again in File2. Thank you in advance.

```
    import csv 

    with open('File1', 'rb') as range, open('File2', 'rb') as timeStamp: 

    range_reader = csv.reader(range, quotechar='"')
    timeStamp_reader = csv.reader(timeStamp, quotechar='"')
    for range_row in range_reader:
      print range_row[2]
      print range_row[3]
      for timeStamp_row in timeStamp_reader:
        print timeStamp_row[2]
        if range_row[2] <= timeStamp_row[2] and range_row[3] >= timeStamp_row[2]
          print " %s falls within %s "% (timeStamp_row[1], range_row[1])
```

Comment: Just a clarification: I would like to take the first line in File1, and iterate thru each of the lines in File2  to see if Timestamp falls within the first Range1. Then take the second line in File1, and iterate again thru each line in File2, then take third line in File1, and iterate again thru each line in File2 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv 

with open('File1.csv', 'rb') as ranger, open('File2.csv', 'rb') as timeStamp: 

    range_reader = [x for x in csv.reader(ranger, quotechar='"')]
    timeStamp_reader = [x for x in csv.reader(timeStamp, quotechar='"')]
    for range_row in range_reader:
        temp = []
        for timeStamp_row in timeStamp_reader:
            if range_row[1] <= timeStamp_row[1] and range_row[2] >= timeStamp_row[1]:
                temp.append(timeStamp_row[0])
        if temp:
            print " %s falls within %s "% (','.join(temp), range_row[0])
```

Lukasas ans is good, but in case if your dataset is large, seek each time in for loop may not be a good idea.
Simply copy them at the beginning.
Besides, to make output as you want, you need to save them at the beginning of outer loop.

```
TimeStamp1 falls within Range1
TimeStamp1,TimeStamp2 falls within Range2
TimeStamp1,TimeStamp2,TimeStamp3 falls within Range3
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in your code. First of all, you've got the indexes messed up. Indexing in this starts at 0. So just substract 1 from all of your indexes.

You can't read from file repeatedly, because the reader will hit it's end and then it won't read anything anymore, because it's at the end. So for the second loop, you need to reset it's reader back to start. That can be easily done by setting the seek.

```py
import csv 
with open('File1', 'r') as ranges, open('File2', 'r') as timeStamp: 
  range_reader = csv.reader(ranges, quotechar='"')
  timeStamp_reader = csv.reader(timeStamp, quotechar='"')
  rangeArray = {}
  for range_row in range_reader:
    print("%s / %s" % ( range_row[1], range_row[2])) # This looks better, and gives more info than just printing both timestamps on each line
    timeStamp.seek(0) # This will set position of cursor in timeStamp back to start, so it can iterate repeatedly
    rangeArray[range_row[0]] = []
    for timeStamp_row in timeStamp_reader:
      if range_row[1] <= timeStamp_row[1] and range_row[2] >= timeStamp_row[1]:
        rangeArray[range_row[0]].append(timeStamp_row[0])
        print (" %s falls within %s " % (timeStamp_row[0], range_row[0]))

print("\n\n")

# Desired Output:
for key in rangeArray:
  print("%s falls within %s" % (', '.join([str(x) for x in rangeArray[key]]), key))
```

This gives output like this:

```
2018-05-17 01:50:17+0000 / 2018-05-17 02:00:17+0000
 TimeStamp1 falls within Range1
2018-05-17 01:50:17+0000 / 2018-05-17 04:00:17+0000
 TimeStamp1 falls within Range2
 TimeStamp2 falls within Range2
2018-05-17 01:50:17+0000 / 2018-05-17 08:00:17+0000
 TimeStamp1 falls within Range3
 TimeStamp2 falls within Range3
 TimeStamp3 falls within Range3



TimeStamp1 falls within Range1
TimeStamp1, TimeStamp2 falls within Range2
TimeStamp1, TimeStamp2, TimeStamp3 falls within Range3
```

Answer (score 1):

As you'll see, I made a lot of alterations, starting with that I wrote the code in Python 3. Are you using Python 2?

Anyway, happy to answer questions. I think this works mostly the way you want it to:

```
import csv 
import datetime


with open('File1', 'r') as range, open('File2', 'r') as timeStamp: 

    range_rows = list(csv.reader(range, quotechar='"'))
    timeStamp_rows = list(csv.reader(timeStamp, quotechar='"'))
    range_list = []
    d=datetime.datetime.now()
    for row in range_rows:
        time = [row[0], d.strptime(row[1][:-5],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), d.strptime(row[2][:-5],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]
        range_list.append(time)
    timeStamp_list = []
    for row in timeStamp_rows:
        time = [row[0], d.strptime(row[1][:-5],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]
        timeStamp_list.append(time)
    for i in range_list:
        for e in timeStamp_list:

            if i[1] <= e[1] and i[2] >= e[1]:
                print(" %s falls within %s "% (e[0], i[0]))
```

Output:

```
 TimeStamp1 falls within Range1 
 TimeStamp1 falls within Range2 
 TimeStamp2 falls within Range2 
 TimeStamp1 falls within Range3 
 TimeStamp2 falls within Range3
```